# Spring multiple levels for candidate picking

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that I can initialize in multiple ways, for example:

- If a bean is configured without any `@Named` / `@Qualifier` / `@Profile` / etc. annotations, pick that one
- Otherwise, if there's a bean with `@Profile`, pick that one
- Otherwise, there's a default bean that is initialized using `@Value("property")`

I.e. something like this as an example:

```
class SpringConfig {
  // Priority 1
  @Bean
  User user() { ... }

  // Priority 2
  @Bean
  @Profile("profile1")
  User user() { ... }

  // Priority 3
  @Bean
  User user(@Value("user") { ... }
}
```

With the above config, the user with "Priority 1" should be picked. Commenting out that bean, the user with "Priority 2" should be picked if "profile1" is enabled. Otherwise (either "profile1" not activated or that bean commented out), it should initialized the user with "Priority 3" using the "user" environment variable.

I don't think `@Primary` would not work here since there are more than two candidates.

There might be more or different kinds of levels or logic to pick them, so this is more a general question about how the Spring configuration should be structured to guide Spring towards picking the right bean.

If that matters, I don't necessarily have to keep the same Spring configuration layout - more looking for a guidance on how to do things properly here.

Comment: Why not configure by profile alone?

Comment: @daniu Env var and profile ones are in a library, which other apps use. Some apps require this default behavior to be changed, hence the need to override. Some apps do not use `@Profile` at all, just resorting to vars. Is there a way to combine these somehow?

Comment: But if the env var one (ie Prio 3, right?) is in a library, you can just use that and set the "user" variable in your application properties as you want.

Comment: @daniu If I specify both var + profile (which some apps do), then profile takes precedence, so var-in-app would be disregarded.

Comment: I really don't seem to have a exact enough picture of how everything is layed out with you. Apps don't really belong in libs, but it sounds like what you have. In general, environment variables do take precedence (eg `java -Duser='name' your.App`), so maybe that's how you can convince your app to use the proper values.